# nn.Linear gives `Only Tensors of floating point and complex dtype can require gradients`

Tags: python, numpy, pytorch

I am trying to understand hon `nn.Embedding` works as `nn.Linear` in case when input is one hot vector.

Consider, input is `[0,0,0,1,0,0]` which is one hot vector corresponding to index 3. So, I first created both:

```
_in = torch.tensor([0,0,0,1,0,0]).long() # used later
_index = torch.LongTensor([3])
```

Then I tried `nn.Embedding`:

```
customEmb = torch.tensor([[1,1,1,1],[2,2,2,2],[3,3,3,3],[4,4,4,4],[5,5,5,5],[6,6,6,6]]).float()
emb = nn.Embedding(d_vocabSize, emb_size) # 6x4
emb.weight = torch.nn.Parameter(customEmb)
print(emb.weight)

print('\n----- embedding(input) ------')
hidden = emb(_index)
print(hidden)
```

which correctly outputted (selected 3rd row in embedding `[4., 4., 4., 4.]`):

```
----- hiddent layer / embedding -----
Parameter containing:
tensor([[1., 1., 1., 1.],
        [2., 2., 2., 2.],
        [3., 3., 3., 3.],
        [4., 4., 4., 4.],
        [5., 5., 5., 5.],
        [6., 6., 6., 6.]], requires_grad=True)

----- embedding(input) ------
tensor([[4., 4., 4., 4.]], grad_fn=<EmbeddingBackward0>)
```

I tried similar with `nn.Linear`:

```
print('\n----- hiddent layer / embedding -----')
customEmb = torch.tensor([[1,1,1,1],[2,2,2,2],[3,3,3,3],[4,4,4,4],[5,5,5,5],[6,6,6,6]]).long()
emb = nn.Linear(d_vocabSize, emb_size) # 6x4
emb.weight = torch.nn.Parameter(customEmb.T)
print(emb.weight)

print('\n----- embedding(input) ------')
hidden = emb(_in) 
print(hidden)
```

For above code, it gave following error:

```
----- hiddent layer / embedding -----
RuntimeError
# ...
---> 16 emb.weight = torch.nn.Parameter(customEmb.T)
# ... 
RuntimeError: Only Tensors of floating point and complex dtype can require gradients
```

So I tried to call `.float()` instead of `.long()` for `customEmb`, but got following error:

```
----- hiddent layer / embedding -----
Parameter containing:
tensor([[1., 2., 3., 4., 5., 6.],
        [1., 2., 3., 4., 5., 6.],
        [1., 2., 3., 4., 5., 6.],
        [1., 2., 3., 4., 5., 6.]], requires_grad=True)

----- embedding(input) ------
RuntimeError
# ...
---> 21 hidden = emb(_in) 
# ... 
RuntimeError: expected scalar type Long but found Float
```

**Q.** What I am missing here?

**PS**

I was expecting `nn.Linear` to return something like:

```
[[0.,0.,0.,0.],
 [0.,0.,0.,0.],
 [0.,0.,0.,0.],
 [4.,4.,4.,4.],     
 [0.,0.,0.,0.],
 [0.,0.,0.,0.],
]
```

**Q.** Somewhat unrelated question: Am I wrong with above expectation?

**Update**

I tried converting both `_in` and `customEmb` to float and error went away:

```
_in = torch.tensor([0,0,0,1,0,0]).float()
customEmb = torch.tensor([[1,1,1,1],[2,2,2,2],[3,3,3,3],[4,4,4,4],[5,5,5,5],[6,6,6,6]]).float()
emb = nn.Linear(d_vocabSize, emb_size) # 6x4
emb.weight = torch.nn.Parameter(customEmb.T)
hidden = emb(_in) 
print(hidden)
```

and it printed:

```
tensor([3.6693, 4.3959, 3.9726, 4.3447], grad_fn=<AddBackward0>)
```

**Q2.** Now am guessing why it is not `[4.,4.,4.,4.]`? Am I completely screwed up with the assumptions / my understanding?

Answer (score 0):

Answering this old post that I recently came across...

The error **Only Tensors of floating point and complex dtype can require gradients** is because the **nn.Linear** module only accepts floating point and complex tensors as input. This is because the weights and biases of the linear layer are also floating point or complex tensors.

To fix this error, you need to make sure that the x tensor is of floating point or complex dtype before passing it to the nn.Linear layer. You can do this by using the **torch.float()** or **torch.complex()** methods to convert the tensor to the desired dtype.

Thus, if your input tensor in non-float, make sure to convert the datatype while passing it in the forward pass:

```
x = layer(input.float())
```